# Should I set the Accept-Language header to "en-gb"?

Tags: html

I am currently trying to work out whether i need to set this below to the en-gb in relation to the accept language header at the top of the page?

The UK currently reads this.

```
xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Would i be right in thinking this should be the following on a UK sub domain.

```
xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb">*
```

Hoping to solve this, as both the UK and USA both contain the same language header which is set on EN-US when looked at through here.

http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/check?uri=uk.reviewanygame.com%2F#validate-by-uri+

[image]

Comment: You don't *need* to do anything. What is the language of the page contents? US English? UK English? Sorta-kinda international English? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

The `lang` attribute should describe the language the document is written in. That is all.

If you wrote it in standard English, it should be `en` or `en-gb`. If you wrote it in American English, it should be `en` or `en-us`.

This has nothing to do with the subdomain the page is hosted on.

---

The `Accept-Language` header is a **request** header. It is sent by the browser. It should not be "at the top of the page".

You should use it to decide which version of the document to serve if you have the same document available in multiple different languages.

It is unlikely that you have the same document written in standard and American English. The effort needed to replace (for example) every instance of *colour* with *color* is unlikely to bring any benefit.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer, just trying to understand why UK urls keep appearing in the USA search, when their is a USA page available.